# UIWebView loading from Sqlite3

Tags: iphone, ios4, uiwebview

I have an NSString variable 'body' that I am populating from sqlite3. 
The string is formatted with '\n' and '\t' such that when printed in NSLog it looks like

```
gagan                   

On 3/21/11 5:36 PM,
From:User91@SMODEVGWS03.com
To:"User91 Test"<User91@SMODEVGWS03.com>
Subject: test it
wrote:

ravan


~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Attachment not downloaded due to unsupported type
```

I am trying to load this string into a UIWebView and still preserve all the formatting for which I browsed and found out this.

```
NSString *body contains the above string with all the formatting.

NSData* data=[body dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

 if (data) {  
[webView loadData:data MIMEType:@"text/html" textEncodingName:@"UTF-8" baseURL:nil];  
       }
```

But I see in the UIWebView the formatting is not preserved and it turns up like this:

```
gagan On 3/21/11 5:36 PM,
From:User91@SMODEVGWS03.com
To:"User91 Test"<User91@SMODEVGWS03.com> Subject: test it wrote: ravan
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~Attachment not 
downloaded due to unsupported type
```

Can anyone come to my rescue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you should add the **p** tag around your string and a br at the end of each line:

```
<p>
gagan<br/>                   
<br/>
On 3/21/11 5:36 PM,<br/>
From:User91@SMODEVGWS03.com<br/>
To:"User91 Test"<User91@SMODEVGWS03.com><br/>
Subject: test it<br/>
wrote:<br/>
<br/>
ravan<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~<br/>
Attachment not downloaded due to unsupported type<br/>
</p>
```

you should use something like this before encoding in UTF8:

```
body = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<p>%@</p>", body];
body = [body stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@"<br/>\n"];
```

Comment: hey, but it stopped following the line breaks as well. Previously the line would change at the end of webview such that it is only vertically scrollable but now it doesn't and my WebView is horizontally scrollable which I don't want.

Comment: I did exactly that but still lines that are bigger than the webview size are not automatically getting truncated at the end of the webView. Instead my webview is becoming horizontally scrollable. That is happening for the last line "Attachment not downloaded due to unsupported type 
"

Comment: Maybe you need to wrap with p instead of pre and add before each new line (\n) a <br/>...

Comment: hey Actually couldn't use the <p> there because the NSString body could sometimes be HTML itself with all the tags and sometimes it is plain text so can't put in a <p> there as it will mess up when the body itself has tags. But I tried without the <p> and just the <br> in place of "\n" and it is working fine. Thanks for help by the way.

Comment: tell me if I don't put the <html> tags on the top and and bottom and just put <br> in the middle which as of now seems to be working fine, will it break sometime in the future?

Comment: I think that should be better to use a valid html file inside a UIWebView. Anyway it should work without any future big issues. If you add <html> which issues do you got?

Comment: If the body string already has HTML tags which is possible in some cases, adding an extra bunch of tags <html> </html> on top of it might have undesirable consequences. Isn't it?

Comment: yes... Maybe you need to check if you have plain text or an html before adding those tags.

Comment: yes precisely my point. Matteo. Will do it. Thanks for the support. By the way how long have you been online. Are you waiting to pounce upon the next question posted to increase your reputation. Ha

Comment: What's your question? I don't think I could help but I am willing to take a look.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5420182/18n-routing-and-redirect-to-proper-urls

Comment: Sorry Matteo! Can't help you there.